# war file created from an ubuntu machine fails to initiate

Tags: vaadin

I am trying to start  the [demo](https://github.com/vaadin/skeleton-starter-flow-spring/tree/v14)  springboot based vaadin  web-app in window10 using the war file built from another instance (ubuntu). However , while it works in ubuntu , it fails to start the embedded Tomcat web server in window10 with the following steps.

1. creating the war file as this doc instructed https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.traditional-deployment.war
2. copy the war file ,  target/ , and the node_modules  into a same directory in window
3. java -jar  flowcrmtutorial-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
4. error occur
   ====================================================================================================

```
 _____  _                     ____  ____   __  __   _____         _                 _         _
|  ___|| |  ___  __      __  / ___||  _ \ |  \/  | |_   _| _   _ | |_   ___   _ __ (_)  __ _ | |
| |_   | | / _ \ \ \ /\ / / | |    | |_) || |\/| |   | |  | | | || __| / _ \ | '__|| | / _` || |
|  _|  | || (_) | \ V  V /  | |___ |  _ < | |  | |   | |  | |_| || |_ | (_) || |   | || (_| || |
|_|    |_| \___/   \_/\_/    \____||_| \_\|_|  |_|   |_|   \__,_| \__| \___/ |_|   |_| \__,_||_|


2023-09-24 18:00:27.604  INFO 13272 --- [           main] com.example.application.Application      : Starting Application v1.0-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.17 on LAPTOP-1AAIV86V with PID 13272 (C:\Users\alex\Desktop\demoTesting\flowcrmtutorial-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war started by alex in C:\Users\alex\Desktop\demoTesting)
2023-09-24 18:00:27.609  INFO 13272 --- [           main] com.example.application.Application      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2023-09-24 18:00:29.395  INFO 13272 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-09-24 18:00:29.617  INFO 13272 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 209 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-09-24 18:00:31.081  INFO 13272 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-09-24 18:00:31.106  INFO 13272 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-09-24 18:00:31.107  INFO 13272 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.45]
2023-09-24 18:00:33.320  INFO 13272 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-09-24 18:00:33.320  INFO 13272 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5607 ms
2023-09-24 18:00:33.645 ERROR 13272 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Running project in development mode with no access to folder '/home/alex/Documents/vaadinTesting/flow-crm-tutorial'.
Build project in production mode instead, see https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/production/tutorial-production-mode-basic.html
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.DeploymentConfigurationFactory.verifyFolderExists(DeploymentConfigurationFactory.java:453) ~[flow-server-2.9.3.jar!/:2.9.3]
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.DeploymentConfigurationFactory.setInitParametersUsingTokenData(DeploymentConfigurationFactory.java:251) ~[flow-server-2.9.3.jar!/:2.9.3]
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.DeploymentConfigurationFactory.readBuildInfo(DeploymentConfigurationFactory.java:191) ~[flow-server-2.9.3.jar!/:2.9.3]
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.DeploymentConfigurationFactory.createInitParameters(DeploymentConfigurationFactory.java:177) ~[flow-server-2.9.3.jar!/:2.9.3]
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.DeploymentConfigurationFactory.createPropertyDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationFactory.java:139) ~[flow-server-2.9.3.jar!/:2.9.3]
        at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$SpringStubServletConfig.createDeploymentConfiguration(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:887) ~[vaadin-spring-12.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:407) ~[vaadin-spring-12.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.lambda$contextInitialized$0(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:180) ~[vaadin-spring-12.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
        at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:180) ~[vaadin-spring-12.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4714) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5172) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at com.example.application.Application.main(Application.java:22) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[flowcrmtutorial-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[flowcrmtutorial-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[flowcrmtutorial-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59) ~[flowcrmtutorial-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:1.0-SNAPSHOT]

2023-09-24 18:00:33.647 ERROR 13272 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2023-09-24 18:00:33.648 ERROR 13272 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2023-09-24 18:00:33.911  INFO 13272 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-09-24 18:00:33.916  WARN 13272 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2023-09-24 18:00:33.927  INFO 13272 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-09-24 18:00:33.958 ERROR 13272 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at com.example.application.Application.main(Application.java:22) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[flowcrmtutorial-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[flowcrmtutorial-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[flowcrmtutorial-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59) ~[flowcrmtutorial-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:187) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        ... 22 common frames omitted

=====================================================================================================
```

I think the cause of the problem is this
"
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Running project in development mode with no access to folder '/home/alex/Documents/vaadinTesting/flow-crm-tutorial'."

if that is the case , how can i config the path so I can run vaadin in development using the war file? or do I need other files/folder ?

Comment: Why do you want to run the WAR in developement mode? Dev-Mode gives you reloading while developing - for a production build brings so many problems...

Comment: because I was trying to  create a proof of concept prototypes to determine whether it is possible to deploy into websphere  first  in order to proceed developing  , and due to my ignorance i didnt know that  the development mode is  a critial factor contributing to the failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A war built for development mode is not meant to be shared on different environments because, as you noticed, it stores some configuration settings specific for the machine you are working on.

If you want to deploy the WAR file on a different system, you need to build it for production.
See https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/production/production-build for details.

Comment: Thanks ,  i am able to  deploy the war built with production mode